# strange warning when using newtxmath and siunitx packages together

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I've just noticed that I'm compiling my documents I get something similar to the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 6.
```

I'm not worrying too much as it's "just" a warning.  My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

I was originally using the `memoir` package and not the Computer Modern fonts and still getting a similar error message about CM fonts.  Which is why I originally noticed it.  Hacked down my list of packages a lot and this is all that seem to be needed to show the behaviour.  The order doesn't seem to matter, and the warning always points to the `\begin{document}`—I presume some code from one of the packages is running there?

Just had more of a read through the scroll back, and see a number of similar warnings for different fonts.

Comment: If you use fix-cm (or the older type1cm) package latex will know that cm fonts are scalable these days and scale to the requested size

Comment: Great, works well in my example and real code.  Thanks!  Do you want to post this as an answer so it can be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `fix-cm` (or the older `type1cm`) package latex will know that cm fonts are scalable these days and scale to the requested size.